# How to pass NSURL object from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSURL` object in `ScanViewController` class and pass it to the `ListViewController` class.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:// some url"];
```

I am using xib's in my project and can't find an alternative for

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    if(error || !data)
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON NOT posted");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON data posted!");
        id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:Nil];

        if([jsonObject respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)])
        {
            NSDictionary *dictionaryForUserID = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"ProjID"];
            NSLog(@" Project Id = %@", dictionaryForUserID);

            NSURL *urlToDisplayInListView = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://some url/%@", dictionaryForUserID]]; **//Pass this object to other viewcontroller**

        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you're performing a segue from one VC to another. If so, you can do this in your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToListViewController"]) {
    [(ListViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:// some url"]];
}
```

You have to declare a property in your destination VC to handle the URL, and you will need an accessor method to set that property.

***EDIT***

As danypata suggested, if you're not using segues, try the following

```
ListViewController *listViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListViewControllerIdentifier"];
[listViewController setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:// some url"]];
[self presentViewController:listViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I think the SO doesn't use `prepareForSegue` since he use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, or he is using it wrong :)). Anyway, you should edit your answer and add a solution for those who don't use segues (they are using `push` methods). Don't be lazy :)). Anyway it's the correct answer for those who are using segues.

Comment: i am not using segue.. the method has (UIStoryboardSegue *) and i am not using storyboards.. how to pass objects in case of xib?

Comment: @DeepakThakur sorry, I've assumed that you were using storyboards. Anyway, what do you have to do is instantiate your VC, set the URL property and present the VC. You will have to add your instantiated VC to a Navigation Controller if you want a push-like action.

Comment: amb : i am NOT using storyboards in my project and want an alternative for [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:].. please edit your answer

Comment: @DeepakThakur you can follow the steps in the comment above, when you instantiate your VC you can send the URL through an accessor method of a property. Let me know If you have trouble instantiating a VC from a ``*.xib``.

Comment: @DeepakThakur you have to access to your instantiated view controller inside the completion handler. You can cache a pointer to your view controller and below NSURL *urlToDisplayInListView... ``[listViewController setURL:urlToDisplayInListView];``

Comment: Glad to help @DeepakThakur!. Remember to mark the answer as accepted if it was useful to you.